# On sharepoint : How to send data from a infopath to an access database

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, sharepoint-addin, access

Good Morning,

I'm new with Sharepoint, i started to use it 1 week ago.

I uploaded on sharepoint an infopath's form and an access Database, those two ones are uploaded
on the same to the sharepoint site.

What i want is when the info path form is finished, the data are sent (when the user filled all the label) directly to access database, who both are on the Sharepoint.

I do not know if it is possible to do this ? If it is should i use work flow ?

I would really appreciate any advice or information .

Thank you for your time and help.